# How to change content of master page dynamically

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am developing a master page for an e-commerce website. I have Left-Side Menubar on the Master Page. This left menubar contains Category list and changes as user change categories. Categories are stored in SQL DB. So, I want to rebuild this menubar as category changes, Is it possible?

Have look on [www.actgreen.com.au/www](http://www.actgreen.com.au/www)

And also I want to create Breadcrumb for website, how can I do.

I am using asp.net 4.0.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried something with code...if yes, then post it here..

Comment: No, I am just creating UI for master page. I am thinking more on these. These website already developed in Classic asp.

Comment: If i will be at your place i will assign some class to a label and then using jquery to update the label. Like assign a class say cssClass="myLabel" and then from master page or content page write ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page , typeof(Page), "scr" ,  "$('.myLabel').text('Updated Content');"   ,true);

Comment: Here, I am using SQL database Approach, so basically, I have category Table which stores categoryID and ParentID. Parent ID for first level is 0, and then it 'll be assigned for Child category and CategoryID will be continued.

Answer (score 0):

Well , we don't know what exact approach you are using in your code to bind left menu..Also you must be binding your left menu in your master page itself. So on each time you click on left menu you can rebind it again by providing some parameter to it.
or if you need to call it from some different page or from  your content pages..then you can try it like this..

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mInfo = this.Page.Master.GetType().GetMethod("RefreshLeftMenu");
mInfo.Invoke(this.Page.Master, null);
```

I do it this way...hope its helpful for you too..

Comment: In page you can get any control of masterpage through Master.FindControl(controlName)

Comment: You can call it directly Master.RefreshLeftMenu(). To do this you must register MasterType on ContentPage: <%@MasterType VirtualPath="Site.Master" %>

Comment: Thanks..for sharing i used to do it this way..but you've suggested another way..which will be helpful for me and otehrs too..

Answer (score 0):

You can use controls on masterpage and change them on page OnLoad

```
Label MyLabelBrand = (Label)Master.FindControl("LabelBrand");
MyLabelBrand.Text = "Fabrikam";
```

If you want to call method `Refresh()` of Master page, you need call `Master.Refresh();`.
To do this you need register master type on ContentPage:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<%@MasterType VirtualPath="Site.Master" %>
```